# jQuery limit characters in div without another div

Tags: jquery

I want to limit the characters in a div to 25 but inside that div I have another div.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#">
      Text that needs to be reduced ti 25 characters.
     <span class='span-class'>span text</span>
</a>

$('a').text(function(index, currentText) {
    return currentText.substr(0, 175);
});
```

But the problem is that is erasing my span since it is in a tag.

I can't modify the stucture of html.

Thanks

EDIT:

This is what I want to achive:

```
<a href="#">
      Text that needs to be red
     <span class='span-class'>span text</span>
</a>
```

I want to reduce the text inside a tag without affecting the span text.

Comment: not able to understand. can u explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("a").contents().each(function(){
 if ($.trim(this.nodeValue) != "" &&  this.nodeType == 3){
     //console.log($.trim(this.nodeValue))
     this.nodeValue = $.trim(this.nodeValue).substring(0,25)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
      Text that needs to be reduced to 25 characters.
     <span class='span-class'>span text</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to uniquely identify the element or this will be applied to all the `a` of the page.

```
var children = $('a').children()

$('a').text(function(index, currentText) {
  return currentText.substr(0, 32);
});

$('a').append(children)
```

Here the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NNGY9ZZnTrQ9P7Y7egve?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
 var restrict = $("a").clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text().substr(0,2);

var children = $("ul").children();
$("ul").text(restrict).append(children)
```